# VBA Code for pasting and Replacing from one Wb to Another

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 excel files. One template that you fill in and one DataBase. The code i've written copies the data from the template wb and pastes it in the DB wb. I want to make it before pasting it to check if some of the values are the same (the values from the template and the values from the last row from the DataBase. 
This is my code so far. I'm new to VBA, i used to code with java so i'm not much aware of how to do things here.

```
Sub DONE()
Dim dataFrom As Range
Dim dataTo As Range
Dim dataBase As Workbook
Dim deleted As Range

'First attempt

Dim nameInWbRng As Range
Dim nameInWb As String
Dim nameInDBRNG As Range
Dim nameInDB As String
Dim dayInWbRng As Range
Dim dayInWb As Date
Dim dayInDbRng As Range
Dim dayInDb As Date
Dim activityInWbRng As Range
Dim activityInWb As String
Dim activityInDbRng As Range
Dim activityInDb As String
Dim destinationInWbRng As Range
Dim destinationInWb As String
Dim destinationInDBRng As Range
Dim destinationInDB As String

Set nameInWbRng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2")
nameInWb = nameInWbRng.Value

Set dayInWbRng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")
dayInWb = dayInWbRng.Value

Set activityInWbRng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2")
activityInWb = acivityInWbRng.Value

Set destinationInWbRng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2")
destinationInWb = destinationInWbRng.Value

'end

Range("E2").Value = Application.UserName

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set dataFrom = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:G2")
Set dataBase = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\katya.atanasova\Desktop\Iskren\Iskren v1.2\DB.xlsx")
With dataBase.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set nameInDBRNG = .Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    nameInDB = nameInWbRng.Value

    Set dayInDbRng = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    dayInDb = dayInWbRng.Value

    Set activityInDbRng = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    activityInDb = acivityInWbRng.Value

    Set destinationInDBRng = .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    destinationInDB = destinationInWbRng.Value

    If nameInDB = nameInWb Then
    If dayInDb = dayInWb Then
    If acitivityInDb = activityInWb Then
    If destinationInDB = destinationInWb Then
    dataFrom.Copy
    Set dataTo = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    dataTo.Replace
    Else


    dataFrom.Copy

    Set dataTo = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    dataTo.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True


End With

dataBase.Close SaveChanges:=True
Set deleted = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F2")
deleted.ClearContents



Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If it finds duplicates i want to replace the data.

Comment: This doesn't compile either. You are missing some `End Ifs` here as well

Comment: Yes, i'm not much familiar with the syntax here

Comment: Every `If` needs to be closed with an `End If` and it should mimic your nesting. So `If.......Then If....Then If...Then [code goes here] ...End If [maybe more code]....End If  [maybe more code].......End If`

Comment: Okay. But is that the correct way to get the values of the Strings ?